# How to create a .bat file to execute java .class files

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I have a java .class file in `D:\Test\aaa\bbb\ccc\test.class`

Say I would like to make a .bat file to execute the test.class and I would like to **put the batch file in the bbb folder.**

I rely on eclipse a lot therefore I am poor at compiling and running programs that are not handled by the ide....

I have tried to make a batch file via notepad and I have tried to make my batch file work

```
@echo off
set JAVA_HOME=d:\tools\jdk1.7.0_80
set path=.;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%path%
```

the only thing I know at the moment is setting the java path

If this were a .java file I would probably write

```
javac \ccc\test.java
java  \ccc\test
```

Like I mentioned I want the .bat file in the bbb folder, not sure if the above is even correct or not

but the real question is that it is a .class file , do I just omit the javac part? or do I have to do something else? what command will correctly execute the batch file and run the test.class?

Answer (score 0):

If the fully-qualified name of the test class is aaa.bbb.ccc.test, i.e. it is in package aaa.bbb.ccc, you should run it from the folder D:\test like this: `java aaa.bbb.ccc.test`

If you want to put your .bat file in bbb\ then there should be two commands in the batch file:

```
cd ../..
java aaa.bbb.ccc.test
```

> but the real question is that it is a .class file , do I just omit the javac part?

javac is the way to make a .class file from a .java file. So, you don't need javac in this case.